# Node.js - Not running DB promises before returning response

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have this request handler on my node server. It has three MongoDB queries, and I want all the results to be returned, before the response is sent.

```
api.get('/getStats/:productID', (req,res)=>{
  let data = {};
  let dailySales = [];
  let avgProduct = "";
  let customers = [];

  Sales.find({productID: productID}).then(
    sales => {
      dailySales = sales;
    }
  );

  Products.find({}).then(
    products => {
      // Calculate Avg product here
      avgProduct = result;
    }
  );

  Customers.find({}).then(
    customers => {
      customers = customers;
    }
  );

  data = {
    dailySales,
    avgProduct,
    customers
  };

  res.json(data);
});
```

But running this returns

```
data: {
  dailySales: [],
  avgProduct: "",
  customers: []
}
```

i.e. The Mongo response is returning before the data is run. Please how to I fix. Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Promsies will start resolving After the current script finishes, so you hit res.json() before you found anything in the database. As answered below, use Promise.all() to wait for all the database results to return, then use res.json() inside the .then() handler at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using the `Promise.all` where you can pass the MongoDB queries as parameter to it ,the promise will be resolved when all the queries return the result in the array

Comment: Can I see an example please

Answer (score 5):

wait for all the promises to resolve before sending the actual response

```
const sales = Sales.find({productID: productID});
const allProducts = Products.find({});
const allCustomers = Customers.find({});

Promise.all([sales, allProducts, allCustomers])
 .then(data => res.json(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try using the in-built [util.promisify](http://farzicoder.com/util-promisify-in-Node-js-v8/) function along with
>   async-await to get data correctly!**

```
const promisify = require('utils').promisify;

const salesFindOnePromise = promisify(Sales.find);
const productsFindAllPromise = promisify(Products.find);
const customersFindAllPromise = promisify(Customers.find);

findDailySalesByIdAsync = async (productID) => {

    try {
        return await salesFindOnePromise({ productID: productID });
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error('Could not fetch the appropriate sales with productID');
    }

}

findProductsAsync = async () => {

    try {
        return await productsFindAllPromise({});
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('Could not fetch sales!');
    }
}

findCustomersAsync = async () => {

    try {
        return await customersFindAllPromise({});
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('Could not fetch customers!');
    }
}


api.get('/getStats/:productID', async (req,res)=>{

try {
  const dailySales = await findDailySalesByIdAsync(productID);
  const avgProduct = await findProductsAsync();
  const customers = await findCustomersAsync();

    const data = {
        dailySales,
        avgProduct,
        customers
    };

    return res.status(200).send(data);

  } catch(err) {
    console.err(`Failed because: {err}`);
    throw new Error('Could not fetch data because of some error!');
  }

});
```